# How to create a Python inbuilt function in local?

Tags: python, python-3.x, function

This might sound a bit crazy but is there a way we can create a Python function in my local and make it behave like an inbuilt function. The purpose is to create a function to clear the console using the below code:

```
import os
clear = lambda: os.system('clear')
clear()
```

Here, I need to define the *clear()* function such that it is available every time I open the Python interpreter the same way I can call any other inbuilt function like print() or max(), etc.

Note: I am not looking to create a function like a bash command but a python function that works inside the interpreter.

Comment: just define you utils module and set PYTHONPATH, and import the module when needed.

Comment: You mean to do it without import ?

Comment: Yes @Kris, am looking to do it without import.

Comment: @LeiYang I am exploring it to be more like an inbuilt function that can be used without importing a module, like print().